# Mongoose: Model.save() doesn't save the array of objects on my MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

My MongoDB is not getting the data I'm trying to save specifically from the array, every other properties are being saved normally.

Here's my Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const SubSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  servicesTitle: {
    title: {
      type: String
    },
    description: {
      type: String
    }
  }
});

const AreaSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  text: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  imageUrl: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  imageDescription: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  services: [SubSchema]
});

const Areas = mongoose.model('Areas', AreaSchema);

module.exports = Areas;
```

How am I handling it?

```
const { //Getting the info from the form
  title, 
  text, 
  imageUrl, 
  imageDescription, 
  servicesTitle, //ARRAY
  servicesDescription  //ARRAY
} = req.body;
```

Then I created a variable called "services" and its value is an array of objects with the servicesTitle and servicesDescription each, like:

```
[
  {
    servicesTitle: 'Example1',
    servicesDescription: 'lalalallalalala'
  },
  {
    servicesTitle: 'Example2',
    servicesDescription: 'lalalallalalala'
  },
  {
    servicesTitle: 'Example3',
    servicesDescription: 'lalalallalalala'
  }
]
```

Then I create a new model with these values and save it:

```
const newAreas = new Areas({
  title,
  text,
  imageUrl,
  imageDescription,
  services
});

newAreas.save()
  .then(areas => {
    res.redirect('/areas');
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Here's the output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOlqK.png
So the exactly amount of items are created but the properties aren't saved. There should be 2 properties inside each object, the servicesTitle and servicesDescription.

Answer (score 0):

Your services object needs to be like below, before passing to save function as per your schema

```
[
  {
    servicesTitle: 'Example1',
    description: 'lalalallalalala'
  },
  {
    servicesTitle: 'Example2',
    description: 'lalalallalalala'
  },
  {
    servicesTitle: 'Example3',
    description: 'lalalallalalala'
  }
]
```

And your schema should be like

```
const SubSchema = {
  servicesTitle: {
    title: {
      type: String
    },
    description: {
      type: String
    }
  }
};
```